# Difference between crystal and mineral

Tags: geology, mineralogy, crystallography

What is the exact difference between a crystal and a mineral?

Comment: Welcome. How are they formed is too broad sorry.

Comment: Almost all minerals are crystals. Not all crystals are minerals. Quartz is both. Sugar is a crystal, but not a mineral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **[crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal)**,

> is a solid material whose constituents (such as atoms, molecules, or ions) are arranged in a highly ordered microscopic structure, forming a crystal lattice that extends in all directions.
>
> Microscopically, a single crystal has atoms in a near-perfect periodic arrangement; a polycrystal is composed of many microscopic crystals (called "crystallites" or "grains"); and an amorphous solid (such as glass) has no periodic arrangement even microscopically.

[image]

Examples of crystals include diamond (C), table salt (NaCl), snow and ice (H<sub>2</sub>O) and chalcopyrite (CuFeS<sub>2</sub>).

[Minerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral) however,

> a solid chemical compound with a fairly well-defined chemical composition and a specific crystal structure that occurs naturally in pure form.

The international Mineralogical Association requirements for classification minerals are:

1. It must be a naturally occurring substance formed by natural
   geological processes, on Earth or other extraterrestrial bodies.
2. It must be a solid substance in its natural occurrence. A major
   exception to this rule is native mercury.
3. It must have a well-defined crystallographic structure; or, more
   generally, an ordered atomic arrangement.
4. It must have a fairly well defined chemical composition. However,
   certain crystalline substances with a fixed structure but variable
   composition may be considered single mineral species.

Consequently, snow and ice are crystals but they are not minerals.

Comment: Ice is actually a mineral, approved by the IMA: https://www.mindat.org/min-2001.html although somewhat polarising because a lot of mineralogists don't consider it as a "real" mineral 

Comment: Every academic mineralogist/petrologist I've known considers ice a mineral; especially given it's importance in planetary geology.